# Is there any way to get the URL of a yammer profile user's homepage via API?

Tags: development, sharepoint-framework, yammer, graph-api

I am trying to find a way to get the link that takes you to the Yammer user's  homepage. I see that the Yammer user's homepage has some kind of ID in the URL.

I developing an app that will show users information on page. When clicked, it will redirect to the Yammer user's homepage, like in the screenshot bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation!

There's an API for fetching the user by email address. https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersby_emailjsonemailuserdomaincom

The response will have that ID.

Comment: I've have never used the yammer api before and i trying to make the requests but it gets to me the message: 

Access to fetch at 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/by_email.json?email=stanley@interfaceit.com.br' from origin 'https://interfaceit.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy

For my understanding the doc says that you have to create a account and register a app, but i did not understand how this works. I cannot just send a request to the rest api? I have to do all the configuration for it?
I looked for another link/tutorial where this is more clear but i did not find it

Comment: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/getting-started Good luck!